# Dynamically insert multiple xml data into sql server tables using single procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml

I need help to insert different format xml data into a SQL Server database using single procedure>

Ex:

```
<Items>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
</Items>

<Products>
    <product></product>
    <product></product>
    <product></product>
</Products>
```

So I need one procedure to insert the data into database taking xml as input. (i have nearly 20 xml formats), I will pass only one xml as input but not all.

Regards
Jayachandra

Comment: **DO NOT** attempt to do this with a single procedure! That will be a huge, messy, kludgy monster and it won't be maintainable over time! If you have 20 formats - you'll need 20 different queries to insert those XML documents into your SQL Server

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: And you have ~20 tables for these xmls?

Answer (score 0):

You may try somethings as:

```
create procedure spInsertData
(
    @data xml
)
as
begin
    set nocount on

    if @data.exist('/Items') = 1
    begin
        insert into Items (Name)
        select T.c.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
        from @data.nodes('/Items/Item') T(c)
        where not exists (select 1 from Items where Name = T.c.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'))

        return;
    end
    else if @data.exist('/Products') = 1
    begin
        insert into Products (Name)
        select T.c.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
        from @data.nodes('/Products/Product') T(c)
        where not exists (select 1 from Products where Name = T.c.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'))

        return;
    end
    -- etc.

end
```

Comment: I will pass either of the xml as input but not both.